# MIPS Help (Modulo or Something Similar)

Tags: mips

[image: Project Description]

I have this project in MIPS and I read in user input of 10 integers into an array of length 10. After reading them I need to iterate through the array and add the odd numbers (not odd numbered elements, any number in the array that isn't even) together and return the sum of the odd numbers. I believe that I am correctly reading in the array but I am not entirely sure(correct me if I am wrong). I need help checking which numbers are odd. I am thinking to use modulo but I don't know how to implement it. Maybe there is a better way that I am not seeing?

[image: Source Code]

Comment: What does 1,3,5,7,9 and all other odd numbers have in common in their binary representation?

Comment: @Harry They all have a 1 bit in the ones place?

Comment: Yes, that's their pattern, modulo 2 is simply looking at the lowest bit. In C you can use `number&1` to get that specific information, guess what instruction that is in assembly.

Comment: @Harry I want to say or, orr maybe, but I really don't know.

Comment: Here's a hint, `number&1` is similar to Molly & Sally, just like Molly AND Sally.